# When working with Azure DevOps and OAuth2, how can you extract user name?

Tags: azure-devops, oauth-2.0, azure-devops-rest-api

We are implementing an application that uses Azure DevOps API using OAuth2.
I have the tokens returned by the token service.

Is there a way to get the username (Display name) for the user from this token?

Comment: Which username do you want to get? Executing user? Or a user from API? So you don't access the API with a PAT?

Comment: We are not using PAT due to cyber restrictions.
I want the name of the user logged in to the browser, that runs our code. The one that was authenticated by OAuth2 authorization service.

Comment: I think you have to use "claims". You can add them in your app registration. It is a bit complex. But with this keyword you Will find something in the internet :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an answer, posting here if someone might wonder as well....

i'm calling the service:
https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/profile/profiles/me?api-version=6.0

with the Token from the token service.